# Interrupting a process in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am new to erlang. 
I wonder if it is possible to interrupt a processor in erlang. Assume we have processor x executing a function f1() that takes a long time to execute. I would like to find an efficient way to interrupt the processor x to execute function f2() and after the execution of f2() it goes back to executing f1() from it was interrupted.

One way of doing this (although not exactly what I want) is to let f1() be executed by a processor (name it, f1_proc), while the creator of f1_proc wait for messages such as [interrupt, f1_terminated, etc ..]  where if interrupt is received f2() is executed.

However, this is not exactly what I want. What if f2() depends on f1() ? in this case, f1() is paused, f2() is executed and then f1() should start from it stopped. I know we can terminate a process, but can we pause them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, this can't be done. There is no way to pause a process from the "outside" without any hook (e.g. `receive` clause) inside the process.

Comment: Thanks ! this is how answers should be .. (I m gonna trust you with that).

Answer (score 0):

I think your question title (processor) is a bit misleading considering you are trying to work with erlang processes.

You should trying working with erlang [hibernate command](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#hibernate-3).
Directly from the above doc link:

```
Puts the calling process into a wait state where its memory allocation 
has been reduced as much as possible, which is useful if the process 
does not expect to receive any messages in the near future.
```

Using timers and message passing between processes you can force your workflow.
i.e. pausing one if it takes too much time, while other continues doing it work.

---

Though your use case is not so clear in the question, you also can have both (infact more) processes working in parallel without having to wait for one another, and also getting notified once a process has finished it's job.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. sorry

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to simply start both functions in different processes. When f2() is dependent on a result from f1(), it `receive`s a message with the needed data. When f1() is done calculating that data, it sends it to the f2() process.

If f2() reaches the receive clause too early, it will automatically pause and wait until the message arrives (hence letting f1() continue its work). If f1(), however, is done first, it will carry on with it's other tasks until preempted automatically by the Erlang process scheduler.

You can also make f1() pause by letting it wait for a message from f2() as well. In that case, make sure that f1() waits AFTER it has sent its message to avoid deadlocks.

Example:

```
f1(F2Pid) ->
   Data = ...,
   F2Pid ! {f1data, Data},
   ... continue other tasks ....

f2() ->
   ... do some work ...,
   Data = receive
             {f1data, F1Data} -> F1Data
          end,
   ... do some work with Data ....

main() ->
   F2Pid = spawn_link(?MODULE, f2, []),
   f1(F2Pid).
```

This message passing is fundamental to the Erlang programming model. You donät need to invent synchronisation or locks. Just receive a message and Erlang will make sure you get that message (and that message only).

I don't know how you are learning Erlang, but I recommend the book *Erlang Programming* by Cesarini & Thompson (O'Reilly). The book covers, in great detail and with good examples, all you need to know about message passing and concurrency.